# How to remove only one of a certain character from a string that appears multiple times in Python 3

Tags: python, string

I was trying to figure out how to remove only a certain character from a string that appears more than once.

Example:

```
>>>x = 'a,b,c,d'
>>>x = x.someremovingfunction(',', 3)
>>>print(x)
'a,b,cd'
```

If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the `3` represent here?

Comment: I'm guessing the `3` means the 3rd occurrence of this char?

Comment: @vascowhite I do not think this is a duplicate: the nth character _of a kind_ and the middle character _of a string_ are two very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the original string by the character you want to remove. Then reassemble the parts in front of the offending character and behind it, and recombine the parts:

```
def remove_nth(text, separator, position):
    parts = text.split(separator)
    return separator.join(parts[:position]) + separator.join(parts[position:])

remove_nth(x,",",3)
# 'a,b,cd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the argument `3` means the occurence of the character in question, you could just iterate over the string and count. When you find the occurence just create a new string without it.

```
def someremovingfunction(text, char, occurence):
    pos = 0
    for i in text:
        pos += 1
        if i == char:
            occurence -= 1
            if not occurence:
                return text[:pos-1] + text[pos:]
    return text
```

Usage example:

```
 print someremovingfunction('a,b,c,d', ',', 3)
```

Answer (score -2):

***This may help***

```
>>> x = 'a,b,c,d'
>>> ''.join(x.split(','))
'abcd'
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for: you are removing all the symbols, not one of them.